# Recursive logic in DAX

Tags: recursion, powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a calculated column that depends on the results from a previous row, and I'm running into a circular dependency issue.

I have an index and a value in the source table, and I'm creating the calculation as follows:

```
TestValue = [Value] +
    CALCULATE(sum([Value]), 
        filter(all(Table), [Index] < earlier([Index]))) + 
                      // running total of previous Value's
    CALCULATE(sum([TestResult]), 
        filter(all(Table), [Index] < earlier([Index]))) 
                      // running total of previous TestResult's
```

and

```
TestResult = if([TestValue] > 10000, [Value])
```

I think the issue is that even though I filtered on `index < earlier (index)`, it is still evaluating `TestResult` for indexes larger than the current one.

What can I do to get this to work?

[Here](http://blog.gbrueckl.at/2015/04/recursive-calculations-powerpivot-dax/) is a link that successfully implemented recursion, but only in scenarios where you multiply an earlier result by a percentage.

Edit:

There seems to be some confusion over what the result should be, so I'll attempt to illustrate the desired outcome:

Original Table

```
| Index | Value |
-----------------
| 1     | 500   |
| 2     | 12000 |
| 3     | 24000 |
```

Expected Result

```
| Index | Value | TestResult | TestValue
----------------------------------------
| 1     | 500   | NULL       | NULL
| 2     | 12000 | 12000      | 500
| 3     | 15000 | 15000      | 500 + 12000 + 12000 = 24500
```

Row three is calculated by the running total of "Value" with index 1 and 2, plus the running total of "TestResult".

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to break down your queries so that there is no circular dependency.

This should return the result you are after:

```
TempValue = [value] + 
  CALCULATE(sum([value]), 
    filter(all('Table'), 
    [index] < earlier([index])))
```

```
TestResult = if([TempValue] > 10000, [Value],0)
```

```
TestValue = [TempValue] + 
  CALCULATE(sum([TestResult]), 
    filter(all('Table'), 
    [Index] < earlier([Index])))
```

Comment: But TestResult needs to look at both TempValue and TestValue in your example above. I don't think what you've provided will give me what I need.

Comment: Until this condition `[TestValue] > 10000` is true, `TestValue` will be equal to `TempValue` so this shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: But even after [TestValue] > 10000, I want to keep calculating... I'm not going to stop once I fulfill that condition.

Comment: The only case when this will not produce the same result is if you have negative `Value`s, is that the case?

Comment: I edited the question to include an example. Hopefully that helps illustrate what I'm trying to do. If your answer does indeed provide the correct result, I apologize. DAX isn't really my strong suit.

Comment: Your expected result is different from what your TestValue intends to do. Because it includes "`[Value] +`", TestValue of Index 1 will be 500 not null.

Comment: Also TestResult of Index 2 will be null not 12000, as the TestValue is less than 10000.